# Incorrect Function value and Derivative when expression in numerator yields zero

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

Recently I found that in special cases when the r.h.s. of a function definition is not simplified, and part of the expression in numerator yields zero, the value of the function is incorrectly zero as well.

i.e.

```
FF[x_] := ((x - (-(1 - z) b))^2 d[x])/(x + (1 - z) b)^2;
FF[-(1 - z) b]
```

The result yields 0. If we take a closer look, actually we have `FF[x]=d[x]`. Clearly, the second line should be `d[-(1 - z) b]`.

A similar problem occurs for function derivative:

```
FF'[-(1 - z) b] == 0
```

I think the reason for this is that somehow `((x - (-(1 - z) b))^2` in the numerator is evaluated first and gives an overall zero. Is this a bug?

Comment: It's normal evaluation at work. The numerator vanishes on substitution whereas the denominator, while equivalent to zero, is not explicitly zero. `In[502]:= FF[x_] := ((x - (-(1 - z) b))^2 d[x])/(x + (1 - z) b)^2;
NumeratorDenominator[FF[x]] /. x -> -(1 - z) b

Out[503]= {0, (b (1 - z) + b (-1 + z))^2}`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau But for product of things, isn't it too hasty to reach a zero result without inspecting every component?

Comment: I'm not sure. I seem to be getting conflicting results (what you saw, or Indeterminate with messages), based on whether I run in standalone kernel or not. I need to make inquiries.